# (User management system) - The first page of the web app is a login page

Tags: angular

Currently the first page of my project display a home page , I want my first page to be a login page. I already created a login-form component . What I understand is if I modify something at app-component (ts & HTML) it will repeat itself as it is the root of project. So how do I make my first page as a login and direct it to home without app-component repeating it ?

Comment: use a guard: https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access and don't allow any path if not guard (else someone can write directly in navigator, e.g. `http:/www.your-direction.com/home` and access to home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep in your browser or on your client side an ID that indicates a login has been done then you can use CanActivate for that.